# how to uppercase date and month first letter of ToLongDateString() result in es-mx Culture?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, internationalization, culture

currently i obtain  the below result from the following C# line of code when in es-MX Culture

```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
                CultureInfo("es-mx");

  <span><%=DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()%></span>
```

## miércoles, 22 de octubre de 2008

i would like to obtain the following

## Miércoles, 22 de Octubre de 2008

do i need to Build my own culture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to build your own culture. You only need to change the property DateTimeFormat.DayNames and DateTimeFormat.MonthNames in the current culture.

i.e.

```
        string[] newNames = { "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo" };
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = newNames;
```

However, it's weird that en-US show months and days with the first uppercase letter and for mx-ES not.

Hope it helps!.

Comment: "it's weird that en-US show months and days with the first uppercase letter and for mx-ES not" - not really, each follows the grammar rules of its language.  In Spanish, day and month names use lower case.

Comment: Hey that's true. I'm Mexican I didn't know that the correct way was using lower case. In Mexico many people write months and days using title case, probably because of an US influence

Comment: if using Microsoft's translation is ok for you you can use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");`

Comment: The problem with using es-ES is that number formatting is different between Mexico and Spain. You'll get commas instead of periods for the decimal, and decimals where you expect commas.

Answer (score 3):

a little late but this work for me!

```
 public static string GetFecha()
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-EC");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

        // maldita sea!
        string strDate = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());

        return strDate.Replace("De", "de");


    }
```

Comment: Worst function name ever. Spanglish is Evil.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern of LongDate for Spanish (Mexico) is

> `dddd, dd' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy`

according to [Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern.aspx). I guess you just have to manually convert the initial letters of the day and month to uppercase or you can use [Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) and then replace "De" with "de".

Comment: This is not a good approach when your I18Ning your work as it requires  intimate knowledge of translations.

Comment: yeah my bad. But how would you approach in culture ignostic way?

Answer (score 1):

The custom long date format string for the invariant culture is "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy", so you can use `string.Format` and a method to handle uppercase:

```
private string GetDateFormated(DateTime date)
{
    return string.Format("{0}, {1} {2} {3}",
        ToTitleCase(date.ToString("dddd")),
        date.ToString("dd"),
        ToTitleCase(date.ToString("MMMM")),
        date.ToString("yyyy"));
}

private string ToTitleCase(string input)
{
    return input[0].ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1);
}
```

Reference: [The long date ("D") format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#LongDate)

Answer (score 0):

first two Solutions works fine but what if we would like to extend this to any culture so i came up with this approach  i change the current culture date time arrays into TitleCase

```
private void SetDateTimeFormatNames()
        {

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = ConvertoToTitleCase(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = ConvertoToTitleCase(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames);

        }

private string[] ConvertoToTitleCase(string[] arrayToConvert)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayToConvert.Length; i++)
                {
                    arrayToConvert[i] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(arrayToConvert[i]);
                }

                return arrayToConvert;
            }
```

how can this be improved with out the Loop?