# Displaying formated Date using Razor/.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to display to the user of my ASP.NET MVC 4 (Razor, C#) web application, a date with this format `Friday, January, 2014` in frensh language which becomes `Vendredi, Janvier, 2014`.

I've tried this

```
@DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek, @DateTime.Today.Month, @DateTime.Today.Year
```

But, using this, I've got : `Friday, 1, 2014`. I've searched in the Net, but, I haven't found much.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom [DateTime format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
@DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd, MMMM, yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks the result was `vendredi, janvier, 2014`, but, how fo I to convert the first letter of word on Maj, please ?

Comment: @user3212730 It may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228559/how-to-uppercase-date-and-month-first-letter-of-tolongdatestring-result-in-es